How to to make a rectangular div with only one side 45deg skewed and other sides should be normal?
I have a div with the code below and i want to make it skewed in one side by 45 degrees and all other three sides should be normal.
<div class="abttitlecont">
    <div class="abttitle"><h1>ِAbout</h1></div>
    <div class="abtco"></div>
</div>

Here is a reference image to how I want the shape to be :

I tried many methods like transform: skew(45deg)
But it didnt work like I expected.
